# prevent Rails trying to use the asset pipeline for images in folder /public/images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use the default Rails behavior for asset precompile on production environment.

Now I have a few hundred product images that is stored in public/images/560  and weekly updated. Therefor I don't want these images in the asset pipeline (otherwise I have to asset precompile everytime the images got updated and restart server, right?).

my products/index view:

```
<div class="image-holder">
    <% if File.file? "#{Rails.root.join('public', 'images', '560')}/#{@product.metauid}_v#{@product.version}.png" %>
      <img class="product-image py-5" src='<%= "#{request.base_url}" %>/images/560/<%= "#{@product.metauid}_v#{@product.version}_geopard_560.png" %>' alt="<%= @product.metauid%>_v<%= @product.version %>_560.png">
    <% else %>
      <%= image_tag("placeholder.png", class: "placeholder") %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

But the image is not shown. In Chrome Inspector I see HTTP Code 303.

How can I prevent Rails trying to use the asset pipeline for images in folder /public/images?

Answer (score 1):

> Therefor I don't want these images in the asset pipeline (otherwise I have to asset precompile everytime the images got updated and restart server, right?).

Yeah. Like user generated images these should not be in the pipeline but just stored in `/public` or better yet a cloud CDN like S3. The assets pipeline is for assets that can be compiled at deploy time.

You might want to consider using ActiveStorage or CarrierWave that both can handle image resizing as well as placeholders instead of reinventing the wheel.

Note you can still have Rails serve files from `/public` that are not part of the assets pipeline. If you want an example try `localhost:3000/robots.txt`. This is really useful in development as you probably don't have NGINX or Apache setup locally to serve the files.

How to disable rails from serving static files depends on your Rails version. Usually this is setup in `config/environments/*.rb`. The config files for recent versions actually default to false for production so that Apache / NGINX serves the files instead.

The setting is also for the entire `/public` directory. You can't just set Rails to not serve a single directory.

### [Rails 4 & 5](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/configuring.html#configuring-middleware)

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.serve_static_files = false 
end
```

### [Rails 6](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/configuring.html#configuring-middleware)

```
Rails.application.configure do
    # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
    # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
    config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
end
```

This is from the generated `config/environments/production.rb` file and is you can see defaults to false unless the env var `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES` is set (the actual value of the env var doesn't matter).

Comment: Thank you very much for the informations. I did config.serve_static_files =  false but the issue is still not resolved. I use MS Windows Server 2018 and IIS. Do you have further ideas what I should try?